# How to connect vapor to mongodb atlas

Tags: swift, mongodb, vapor, mongodb-replica-set, mongodb-atlas

So I have a `vapor` \ `fluent` app that works fine with local mongo instance, here's current `mongo.json`:

```
{
    "database" : "vapor",
    "port" : "27017",
    "host" : "127.0.0.1",
    "user" : "",
    "password" : ""
}
```

I've deployed a free `MongoDB Atlas` 3 replica set and I wonder how do I connect the app to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fluent's MongoDB integration is using an outdated version of MongoKitten. Currently we're at MongoKitten 4. MongoKitten 1, which is being used in Fluent currently supports just a fraction of the features with a much worse performance.

Answer (score 0):

- Check that your mongod instance is listening on the necessary network interfaces
- Check that your firewall is open and you can connect to the mongod process from your application node
- Check that your mongod is secure, i.e. you can connect only with known credentials
- In the application's mongo.json:

```js
"host": "replica_set_name/first_RS_node_address, second_RS_node_address, third_RS_node_address", 
"user": "your_user_name", 
"password": "wery_secret"
```

Comment: I'm getting this error when trying to connect: `The MongoDB background loop encountered an error: Socket failed with code 9 ("Bad file descriptor") [readFailed]`

Comment: Can you connect to that mongod with telnet from you application node? If not, check your connection.